# oncompletionlistener mediaplayer insert in code

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to add onCompletionlistener mediaplayer in the below program,so when my audio completed it should notify through Toast and textshow should be  set to "  ".
But it doesnot damage my code that is play and stop vice versa.

package project.kalmas;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class one extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp=null;
    TextView textshow; 
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.one);


     }

     public void onclick2(View view)
     {
         Intent i=new Intent("project.two");
         startActivity(i);
     }

                public void onclick3(View view) {
                     textshow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textshow);
                    if (mp == null) {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(one.this, R.raw.one);
                        mp.start();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textshow.setText("Playing...");
                        textshow.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp = null;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textshow.setText("Stopped...");
                        textshow.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it by creating `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` listener:

```
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener
                      = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){    
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // set TextView text here
      // show Toast here
   }
};
```

set it to `MediaPlayer` by calling `setOnCompletionListener` :

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(one.this, R.raw.one);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
mp.start();
```

Comment: I dont know where to edit it,Can you add it in my post and repost it?i will appreciate then.

Comment: @RameelHashmi : use `completionListener` code after `onCreate` method and `setOnCompletionListener` inside `onclick3` click

Answer (score 0):

this is updated code as suggested by you i edited the things.
package project.kalmas;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class one extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp=null;
    TextView textshow;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.one);


     }
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener
        = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){    
         @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    textshow.setText(" ");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
};

     public void onclick2(View view)
     {
         Intent i=new Intent("project.two");
         startActivity(i);
     }

                public void onclick3(View view) {
                     textshow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textshow);
                    if (mp == null) {
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(one.this, R.raw.one);
                        mp.start();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textshow.setText("Playing...");
                        textshow.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp = null;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textshow.setText("Stopped...");
                        textshow.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }               
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(one.this, R.raw.one);
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
                    mp.start();

}
}
```